# Available Schema Types MongoDb/Mongoose

Tags: node.js, validation, mongoose

I would like to find a to know every field available on a Schema.
Basically, we have the MongoDB doc: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/schematypes.html

I also searched in the mongoose doc: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html

But so far I found NOTHING about field such as minLength/maxLength, I'm sure they exists because I use them. I wanted to know if they was a field `length` to check the size of a string.

This kind of doc should exists somewhere, no?
And, I also wanted to know if I can add field that doesn't exists in mongo/mongoose. Such as length if it doesn't, or it will throw an error?

Edit: I'm not longer so sure about minLength/maxLength. Could someone tells me if they really exists or if I added them by myself? That would means that it's possible to add his own fields.

```
email: {
    type: 'string',
    lowercase: true,
    minLength: 4,
    maxLength: 30,
    required: true,
    notEmpty: true,
    unique: true
},
```

Comment: I just tried and actually it's possible to add whatever I want as field, it's not checked. So it's higly probable that these fields don't exists at all.

Comment: I don't understand your question(s)? Your not sure about `minLength`/`maxLength`? What aren't you sure about? Those validation attributes don't exist without a plugin.

Comment: I don't use any plugin. I guess I added them by myself so. I actually use my own validator based on these fields. Because I didn't add them by myself (minLength, etc. because we are several people on the project) I assumed that was basically some properties from mongoDb/Mongoose but it looks like I was wrong.